# Is there any way to navigate from Visual studio code extension's webview to external Windows application?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a Visual Studio Code extension which opens a webview on some event. Webview has some links with the below link address:

reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_2

With this URI, I should be navigated to an external Windows application. When I use this URI in Chrome/Firefox browser, I am able to navigate to the targeted external Windows application. But from within my extension's webview, when I hit this link, I am getting below error:

`Uncaught Error: [UriError]: If a URI does not contain an authority component, then the path cannot begin with two slash characters ("//")`

I tried to replace all the "//" with "/" making the URI : 
reqtify:/NKR8WIN764PLP/Users/Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_2

But still, I am not able to navigate to external Windows application.

Here is my code to render the webview:

```
protected async doUpdate(): Promise<void> {
   let content: string;
   this.throttleTimer = undefined;
   content = await this.contentProvider.provideRequirementsContent(document.uri, 
             this.state, this.editor.webview);            
        this.editor.webview.options = getWebviewOptions(this.contentProvider);
        this.editor.webview.html = content; 
}

protected static getWebviewOptions(contentProvider: BaseContentProvider
): vscode.WebviewOptions {
    return {
        enableScripts: true,
        localResourceRoots: contentProvider.localResourceRoots
    };
}

public async provideRequirementsContent(sourceUri: vscode.Uri, state: any, webview: any): Promise<string> {
   let html =       "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">        
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="sect2">
      <h2>
      <span class="numbering">1.   </span>Requirements of Specifications</h2>
          <table width="100%" align="center">
          <colgroup>
          <col width="80"></col>
          <col width="1*"></col></colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Requirement</th>
              <th>Text</th></tr></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_1">SPEC_1</a></td>
              <td>For any of the cruise control (CC) functions to take effect, CC must be turned on first.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_2">SPEC_2</a></td>
              <td>CC can be in the following states: off, enabled (i.e., on and cruising), and disabled (on, but not cruising).</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_3">SPEC_3</a></td>
              <td>The CC system should be automatically disabled below 30mph and above 90mph.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_4">SPEC_4</a></td>
              <td>Four actions are permitted during CC: set speed, accelerate, decelerate, and resume speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_5">SPEC_5</a></td>
              <td>When the system is under CC and the brake is pressed, CC is disabled. When the resume button is pressed, the system resumes at the last set CC speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_6">SPEC_6</a></td>
              <td>When the system is under CC and the accelerator pedal is pressed, CC is disabled and the speed increases correspondingly. When the accelerator is released, the CC resumes at its last set CC speed. If at any point of time during acceleration the CC speed is set, CC replaces the old set speed with the new speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_7">SPEC_7</a></td>
              <td>If CC is enabled and the vehicle starts going uphill or downhill, CC should automatically apply the accelerator or brake to maintain the set speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_8">SPEC_8</a></td>
              <td>You can assume an automatic transmission vehicule.</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
    </body>
    </html>
    "

html = html.split('reqtify:////').join('reqtify:/');
html = html.split('//Public').join('/Public');
}
```

I want to navigate to an external Windows application with these HTML content links. Could you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I managed to solve this in some way, but I am not sure whether it is correct way.

I appended a script to above HTML string which contains a method that is called on load event of body.

So, my final HTML string will be like:

```
let html =       "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()>

    <div class="sect2">
      <h2>
      <span class="numbering">1.   </span>Requirements of Specifications</h2>
          <table width="100%" align="center">
          <colgroup>
          <col width="80"></col>
          <col width="1*"></col></colgroup>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Requirement</th>
              <th>Text</th></tr></thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_1">SPEC_1</a></td>
              <td>For any of the cruise control (CC) functions to take effect, CC must be turned on first.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_2">SPEC_2</a></td>
              <td>CC can be in the following states: off, enabled (i.e., on and cruising), and disabled (on, but not cruising).</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_3">SPEC_3</a></td>
              <td>The CC system should be automatically disabled below 30mph and above 90mph.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_4">SPEC_4</a></td>
              <td>Four actions are permitted during CC: set speed, accelerate, decelerate, and resume speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_5">SPEC_5</a></td>
              <td>When the system is under CC and the brake is pressed, CC is disabled. When the resume button is pressed, the system resumes at the last set CC speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_6">SPEC_6</a></td>
              <td>When the system is under CC and the accelerator pedal is pressed, CC is disabled and the speed increases correspondingly. When the accelerator is released, the CC resumes at its last set CC speed. If at any point of time during acceleration the CC speed is set, CC replaces the old set speed with the new speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_7">SPEC_7</a></td>
              <td>If CC is enabled and the vehicle starts going uphill or downhill, CC should automatically apply the accelerator or brake to maintain the set speed.</td></tr>
            <tr>
              <td><a href="reqtify:////NKR8WIN764PLP/Users//Public/Documents/Reqtify/2020x/Examples/Coupling/Code/Code%20C/Code%20Sample.rqtf?id=SPEC_8">SPEC_8</a></td>
              <td>You can assume an automatic transmission vehicule.</td></tr></tbody></table></div>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
            let reqs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
            for (let item of reqs) {                                                    
                item.addEventListener('click', function() {                                                                                                  
                    vscode.postMessage({
                        command: 'open',
                        text: item.getAttribute('href')
                    })                                                    
                    return false;
                  }, false);
            }                                                                                                
        } 
    </script>    
    </body>
    </html>
    "
```

If you observe the script, I am using `vscode.postMessage({})` to send a message [containing command "open" and url as data] which will be received by **onDidReceiveMessage** method of webview as below:

```
        this.editor.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(message => {
            switch (message.command) {
                case 'open':
                        var url = message.text;
                        var start = (process.platform === 'darwin'? 'open': process.platform === 'win32'? 'start': 'xdg-open');
                        require('child_process').exec(start + ' ' + url);   
            }
        }, null, super.disposables);
```

As and when "open" command is received from postMessage, I am navigating to external application using url with the help of Nodejs API.

Thank you.

Comment: This is the correct approach. However to help other people who are interested in this question, please consider condensing it so that it just contains the important code (for example, the styles and actual page content are not relevant)